# Need help for Migration from Google Maps API v2 to v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am migrating my application from Google maps API v2 to v3.
I have two different keys in use(one for static http and other for SSL(https))
But, when now I applied for v3 key from this site  https://code.google.com/apis/console I got only one key.
So, is this one key enough for both http and https or is there any other place where I can get key for https?
Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one key enough for both http and https and also for Google maps API v2 to v3

Comment: but in v2 version I have used 2 keys..won't that be a problem?

Comment: thanks @Kunal and I also have an another doubt..whether Google is giving https support for free or for premium users only..?

Comment: The Google Maps JavaScript API V3, Google Static Maps API, and Google Maps API Web Services can be accessed over secure (HTTPS) connections by developers using either the free version of these APIs or Google Maps API for Business. Please see the documentation for the API concerned for information on how to access the API over SSL. [Google MAP with HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#ssl)